# SkSpriteNode has no member center

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have an SKSpritenode named "Ghost" and I am trying to add a pulsing look to the outside of the image. However I am getting an error saying it has no center, I am not sure how fix this please help.

```
func addPulse(){
        let pulse = Pulsing(numberOfPulses: .infinity , radius: 110, position: Ghost.center)
        pulse.animationDuration = 1.0
        pulse.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(pulse, below: Ghost.layer)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKSpriteNode` extends `SKNode`. Neither has a `center` property. However, there is `frame` and `position`. Use either of those properties instead of `center`.

```
let pulse = Pulsing(numberOfPulses: .infinity , radius: 110, position: Ghost.position)
```

Comment: That removed the center error, however i now have an error saying there is no layer for Ghost

Comment: `SKNode` isn't a view and it doesn't have a layer. But that's a completely separate question from the one you posted here. Close this question and post a new question specific to your "layer" issue.

Comment: I am unable to ask another question, could you help me fix this error

Comment: you are mixing 2 different technologies, UIKit and SpriteKit.  I do not know what `Pulsing` is, but you need to get that to be a member of the SpriteKit family to get what you want to work, or not use SpriteKit at all